# Like in Textarea, can we add a drag in columns of table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In textarea, we can drag the box. Likewise, can we add the option of drag function ( same in textarea ) in columns of the tables using pure javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`resize` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize), which does exactly that.

Comment: Then you need to write Javascript to handle mouse events and set the size.